# Left aligning centered equations

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

I have set of equations which I would like to just assign one number to. The equations should be aligned at the center of the page. The problem is that I would like all equations to begin at the same point whereas now they end at the same point. I use the `\usepackage{amsmath}`. Using the following input:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
u_1 = \partial \phi_1 / \partial x + \partial \psi_1 / \partial z \\
w_1 = \partial \phi_1 / \partial z - \partial \psi_1 / \partial x \\
u_2 = \partial \phi_2 / \partial x \\
w_2 = \partial \phi_2 / \partial z
\label{eq2.23}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

I get the following output:

[image]

The problem is that I want the u2 and w2 to appear directly below u1 and w1. If anyone can help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Or put `&` at the beginning of each row to align the left-hand edge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the alignment tab `&` to justify the equations, i.e. substitute `=` by `&=`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
u_1 &= \partial \phi_1 / \partial x + \partial \psi_1 / \partial z \\
w_1 &= \partial \phi_1 / \partial z - \partial \psi_1 / \partial x \\
u_2 &= \partial \phi_2 / \partial x \\
w_2 &= \partial \phi_2 / \partial z
\label{eq2.23}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I didn't realize it was that easy :).  Really appreciate it!

Comment: @Kristian If you want to learn more about the possibilities in mathmode, [this](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/voss-mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) might be interesting.